# how to trim a string with specific condition of trimming

Tags: c#, string, trim

I want to trim an email to get the username only. In other words for example I have :

```
admin@example.com
```

I want to trim this string to get admin only that is trim everything after the @ sign using mvc 5 or C# how could that happen?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to have your work done for you for free. Provide what you have tried and we can help fix anything that might not be working.

Comment: Have a look at `Substring` and `IndexOf`

Comment: "how could that happen?" go to stackoverflow and show some of your work... then you will get some help... or go to google and search and read and try.

Answer (score 3):

```
string test = admin@example.com

string[] arr = test.Split('@');

string userNAme = arr[0];
```

Here next time use google ...

You can see this [examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) and this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: next time do not answer to question that are clearly out of SO rules...